# Selenium Java and visable table testing

Tags: java, selenium, html-table

I am trying to work with a table here and it has my head cooked to a fine crisp. 
So the test is, load the page and confirm the “Load Schedule” button is there. Also assert that the Table headers are present and contain the expected text. That is complete and working. 
Here is the HTML off the table before clicking on “Load Schedule”

```
<table id="scheduleTable" class="audit_table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th class="date-header red_grade">Kick Off(UTC)</th>
            <th class="narrow-header red_grade">RBallId</th>
            <th class="narrow-header red_grade">GSMId</th>
            <th class="narrow-header red_grade">WBId</th>
            <th class="country-header red_grade">Country</th>
            <th class="header red_grade" style="display:none">Sport</th>
            <th class="header red_grade" style="display:none">SportId</th>
            <th class="header red_grade">League</th>
            <th class="header red_grade ">Home</th>
            <th class="header red_grade">Away</th>
            <th class="header red_grade">Languages</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when I click the Load Schedule button, a new “tbody” element is added to the page as so:

```
<tbody><tr class="odd">
        <td class="Kickoff">2013-09-02 14:30:00</td>
        <td class="RBallId">327097</td>
        <td class="GSMId">0</td>
        <td class="WBId">0</td>
        <td class="Country">South Africa-(82)</td>
        <td class="Sport" style="display:none">Soccer</td>
        <td class="SportId" style="display:none">1</td>
        <td class="League">Varsity Football Challenge</td>
        <td class="Home">University of the Western Cape - UWC (students)</td>
        <td class="Away">University of Cape Town - UCT (students)</td>
        <td class="Languages"></td>
</tr><tr class="even">
        <td class="Kickoff">2013-09-02 14:45:00</td>
        <td class="RBallId">338082</td>
        <td class="GSMId">0</td>
        <td class="WBId">0</td>
        <td class="Country">Friendly-(20)</td>
        <td class="Sport" style="display:none">Soccer</td>
        <td class="SportId" style="display:none">1</td>
        <td class="League">Friendly INT Women U19</td>
        <td class="Home">Greece U19</td>
        <td class="Away">Turkey U19</td>
        <td class="Languages"></td>
</tr><tr class="odd">
        <td class="Kickoff">2013-09-02 15:00:00</td>
        <td class="RBallId">336937</td>
        <td class="GSMId">1421234</td>
        <td class="WBId">0</td>
        <td class="Country">Estonia-(2)</td>
        <td class="Sport" style="display:none">Soccer</td>
        <td class="SportId" style="display:none">1</td>
        <td class="League">Meistriliiga</td>
        <td class="Home">Kalju</td>
        <td class="Away">Kuressaare</td>
        <td class="Languages"></td>
</tr><tr class="even">
        <td class="Kickoff">2013-09-02 15:00:00</td>
        <td class="RBallId">331340</td>
        <td class="GSMId">1571623</td>
        <td class="WBId">0</td>
        <td class="Country">Sweden-(48)</td>
        <td class="Sport" style="display:none">Soccer</td>
        <td class="SportId" style="display:none">1</td>
        <td class="League">U21 B-Playoffs</td>
        <td class="Home">Halmstad U21</td>
        <td class="Away">Kalmar U21</td>
        <td class="Languages"></td>
</tr><tr class="odd">
        <td class="Kickoff">2013-09-02 15:00:00</td>
        <td class="RBallId">331348</td>
        <td class="GSMId">1571636</td>
        <td class="WBId">0</td>
        <td class="Country">Sweden-(48)</td>
        <td class="Sport" style="display:none">Soccer</td>
        <td class="SportId" style="display:none">1</td>
        <td class="League">U21 B-Playoffs</td>
        <td class="Home">Åtvidaberg U21</td>
        <td class="Away">Gefle U21</td>
        <td class="Languages"></td>
</tr><tr class="even">
```

And so on and on and on.

What I want to be able to do, is to check that before I click the button, the only thing visible is the Header, and then when I click the “Load Schedule” button, I want to take the row count and assert that it is > 0.

I have tried several examples from here and from Google but haven’t had much joy in getting any off them to work in the manner I wish.

I did the below as another method but that failed badly:

```
    private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriverBackedSelenium webBrowser, String xpath) {
    try {
        driver.getWrappedDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"scheduleTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]"));
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As usual  I appreciate any time taken to help me out on this one

Comment: Have you tried using find WebElements then use the .size operator?

Comment: Well your method is very very badly wrong. You pass in a `WebDriverBackedSelenium` and an `XPath` and use **neither** of them. So I'm not surprised it doesn't work. What happens? What errors? What browser?

Comment: Apologies Adam, method was created by hacking examples together. I have been doing Selenium for 4 weeks now and java the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a combination of `WebDriverWait` for explicit wait and `ExpectedConditions` class for out of the box wait conditions for situations mentioned above. Also I would recommend avoiding `xpath` for reasons which are well documented in selenium community. Here is a sample code,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
//check visibility of only headers
By header_locator = By.cssSelector("table#scheduleTable>thead>tr>th");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(header_locator));
//make sure schedules are not present
By schedule_locator = By.cssSelector("table#scheduleTable>tbody>tr");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(schedule_locator));

//now click on Load Schedule Button and make sure schedule appear

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(schedule_locator));
```

Some useful links

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Thanks for the example nilesh, I will check this in the morning once back at the office as the VPN software does not like Win8.1. I will report back!

Comment: Worked perfect nilesh, thanks very much indeed. Have you any links to good resource for selenium learning. Anything I have found is pretty poor to be honest. All basic stuff and there doesn't seem to much advanced tuts around

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I updated the answer with few links. I learnt by following these links and blogs from experts. Its good to post questions on SO too. I also found it useful and educational to just browse through list of questions on SO for selenium/webdriver tags. You would learn know approaches/techniques/tips etc.